# When I use a x-amz-tagging in header it gives 403 forbidden error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers, vercel, pre-signed-url

Hi I have a working serverless function that uses s3 signedurl to put a file in an s3 bucket using on the Serverless framework that I am trying to migrate to a vercel serverless function using Next.

The function works via the serverless function and Postman, but when I try on Vercel although it generates the signedurl ok but when I try to use it with a `"x-amz-tagging"="test"` header I get a 403 error. Here is the relevant bit of my code:

```
//serverless function
const allowCors = fn => async (req, res) => {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT')
        res.setHeader(
           'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
           'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, x-amz-tagging, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version'
        )
        return await fn(req, res)
}

function requestUploadURL(req, res) {
...
}
module.exports = allowCors(requestUploadURL)
```

```
//code in app
try {
   const config = {
       onUploadProgress(progressEvent) {
        const percent = Math.round(
          (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
            adduploadprogress({
              file: fileSelectedArray[i].file,
              fileType: fileSelectedArray[i].fileType,
              myFsize: fileSelectedArray[i].myFsize,
              percent,
            })
        },
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': fileSelectedArray[i].fileType,
           'x-amz-tagging': 'test', // THIS CAUSES 403 ERROR
                                                            
        },
}

const resp1 = await axios.put(
  uploadURL,
  fileSelectedArray[i].file,
  config
)
```

Any advice gratefully received

Comment: tags should have the form `name=value&name2=value2&...`, not just `name`. And does your presigned url  allow specifying a tag?

Comment: Thanks @luk2302. This tagging does work OK on the Serverless framework although maybe it is not standard and I believe it is allowing tagging as it was on the Serverless version, although I am not sure if I have configured the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' correctly. Previously I did not have to use this. I only used 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true, and 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'

Comment: I have removed the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' altogether and it still gives a 403 both with 'x-amz-tagging': 'test' and 'x-amz-tagging': 'name=test'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I also need to use `Tagging:''` as part of the s3 params in the function being wrapped by the `allowCors` function. I didn't need to do this before

```
const { body } = req
        const s3Params = {
                Bucket: UNIQUEBUCKET,
                Key: body.name,
                ContentType: body.type,
                ACL: 'public-read',
                Tagging: '',
        }

        const uploadURL = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params)
```